# How to unhide messages from certain js file in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I was working on a website and accidentally on console i hid the messages from my js file. Now i am not able to undo it.

I tried messing around with the console but i couldn't see an option to undo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Filter field and a dropdown for the levels of messages that are shown.

[image]

Make sure the filter is empty and you've selected all the levels in the dropdown.